# mysql error while creating table defining foreign keys

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

create database Geomart;

use geomart;

**##Creating the table customers**

```
 create table customers (
  CustomerID int not null,
  Customer_Name varchar (20),
  address varchar(50),
  City varchar(20),
  Postal_code int,
  Country varchar(20),
  primary key(CustomerID)
  );
```

**##Creating the Table Categories**

```
create table Categories (
category_ID int not null,
Category_Name Varchar(20),
descriptions varchar(50),
primary key(Category_ID)
);
```

**##Creating the table employees**

```
create table employees (
employee_ID int not null,
Last_name Varchar(20),
First_Name varchar(20),
Bith_Date date,
Notes varchar(50),
primary key(employee_ID)
);
```

**##Creating the table Shippers**

```
Create table Shippers (
Shipper_ID int not null,
Shipper_name varchar(20),
phone int,
primary key(shipper_ID)
);
```

**##Creating the table Orders** - Error

```
create table orders (
order_ID int not null,
customerID int,
employee_ID int,
order_Date date,
Shipper_ID int,
primary key(order_ID),
foreign key(customerID) references customers,
foreign key(employee_ID) references employees,
foreign key(shipper_ID) references shippers
);
```

### I am getting the error - Error Code: "1239. Incorrect foreign key definition for 'foreign key without name': Key reference and table reference don't match"

tried creating a table with multiple foreign keys in a single table. Is it possible

Comment: You need to specify the referenced column as well as table eg foreign key(customerID) references customer(customerid) https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Comment: as mentioned by @P.Salmon you need to provide the reference to the key with the table. Like `foreign key(customerID) references customers(CustomerID)`  and so on